# Parsing XML in php, parser errors start tag expected

Tags: php, xml

So trying to take an xml provided with a url and then format the data into a html table with php. Am I meant to apply some kind of formatting to the xml so that it can read it as a simplexmlelement?

```
$url = 'myxmlurl'
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
```

and then I get these nice errors:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\xmldisplay\test.php on line 7

Warning: simplexml_load_string():  in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\xmldisplay\test.php on line 7

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\xmldisplay\test.php on line 7
```

Edit: file_get_contents fixed the error. Now I'm getting a new on when I try to loop.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));
foreach ($xml->assets->asset as $assetElement) {
  $html="
<tr>
  <td class='text-left'><strong>"/*.$assetElement.*/."</strong></td>
  <td class='text-left'><strong>".(string)$assetElement->effectiveDate."</strong></td>
  <td class='text-left'><strong>".(string)$assetElement->buyPrice."</strong></td>
  <td class='text-left'><strong>".(string)$assetElement->sellPrice."</strong></td>
</tr>";
```

}

It doesn't like my foreach

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\xmldisplay\test.php on line 26
```

Comment: have you checked wheater string is valid or not ?

Comment: I just used the following to check it and it came back true:

        $xml = XMLReader::open($url);

// The validate parser option must be enabled for
// this method to work properly
$xml->setParserProperty(XMLReader::VALIDATE, true);

var_dump($xml->isValid());

Comment: is this the whole code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding file_get_contents():

```
$url = 'https://perennialonline.com.au/asset/?req=asset&auth=pere123&do=read_all&fund_id=PVDCIT&start_date=01-01-2013&end_date=01-01-2050'
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));
```

If you want to pass directly the url instead, check the signature of the SimpleXMLElement class:

```
final public SimpleXMLElement::__construct (
    string $data
    [, int $options = 0
    [, bool $data_is_url = false
    [, string $ns = ""
    [, bool $is_prefix = false ]]]]
)
```

You must code this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, null, true);
echo $xml->asXml();
```

Comment: If I solved your problem, please accept my answer as right